# Sum over logical expression as index

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, notation

I am struggling with the interpretation of the following series' notation.

$y(s,t) = \sum_{s \in S_i \wedge t \in T_i} \frac{R_i}{W(S_i)|T_i|}$

where $s$ is an atomic element of the finite set $S_i = \{s_{i1}, s_{i2}, ..., s_{in}\}$, $R_i \in \mathbb{N}$ is some natural number (the index $i \in \mathbb{N}$ has a meaning beyond the context of the question that is not relevant here), the function $W(S_i)$ evaluates to some natural number $\mathbb{N}$, i.e., $W: S_i \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ and $T_i = \{t_{i1}, t_{i2}, ..., t_{in}\}$ being another finite set.

Specifically, I am struggling with the indexing over the logical expression $s \in S_i \wedge t \in T_i$ over which the sum is evaluated. I suppose the logical expression $s \in S_i \wedge t \in T_i$ should evaluate to either True or False. If it evaluates to True a term in the form $\frac{R_i}{W(S_i)|T_i|}$ should add to the sequence, right?

Suppose we have the following concrete example:

$S_1 = \{s_{11}\}$ is a set with only a single [atomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urelement) element.
$T_1 = \{t_{11}, t_{12}, t_{13}\}$ is a set with three elements, hence $|T_1| = 3$. Let $R_1 = 500$ and $W(S_1) = 2000$.

Can someone use that example to show me how e.g., $y(s_{11}, t_{11})$ is evaluated using the definition of $y(s,t)$ above? As far as I understand it, and that might be completely wrong hence my question here, for $y(s_{11}, t_{11})$ there exists only a single tuple $(s,t) = (s_{11}, t_{11})$ for which the logical expression $s \in S_i \wedge t \in T_i$ evaluates to "True" in this particular example. Therefore, the series $y(s_{11}, t_{11})$ contains only a single term $\frac{R_i}{W(S_i)|T_i|} = \frac{500}{2000 * 3} \approx 0.08$.

But if that is the case, then - given that we always only pass a particular tuple $(s,t)$ to $y(s,t)$ when can there ever be multiple factors in the series? Thus, the notation with the sum would be completely off... Or - what I personally deem more likely - I don't understand the notation. By the same token, this would mean that $y(s_{11},t_{11}) = y(s_{11},t_{12}) = y(s_{11},t_{13})$ in the example, since there always exists just one tuple $(s,t)$ for which the logical expression evaluates to True - and none of the values in the fraction ever change independently of the tuple that is passed to the function $y(s,t)$.

Thank you in advance

**Edit: Context of the question.**

Ok so the context is a trading agent designed by [Tao, Wu & Chen (2015)](https://www.cs.sjtu.edu.cn/%7Efwu/res/Paper/TWC15AAMAS.pdf) for a Trading Agent Competition.

The Game is a Display Advertising Market in which Agents compete in auctions for both display advertising campaigns and for impressions. These auctions are second-price auctions, hence it is a [weakly dominant strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategic_dominance) to bid one's true valuation for the item at sale.

The question is how to determine that valuation for the item at sale. The particular auction I am concerned here is the one for advertising campaign contracts. A contract $C_i(R_i, S_i, T_i)$ is characterized by the required reach $R_i$, the targeted user segment $S_i$, e.g., (YOUNG $\wedge$ FEMALE $\wedge$ LOW_INCOME), and the duration of the campaign $T_i$, i.e., a series of days in which the day is conducted in (a game consists of $T_{Gamedays} = 60$ periods).

The function $W(S_i)$ is simply the population of the respective segment $S_i$, e.g, 2000. I provide the concrete data used in the game below. Every row corresponds to a segment $s$. A campaign might targeted some composition of atomic segments such as $S_i= FEMALE$, such that $S=${YOUNG $\wedge$ FEMALE $\wedge$ LOW_INCOME, YOUNG $\wedge$ FEMALE $\wedge$ HIGH_INCOME, OLD $\wedge$ FEMALE $\wedge$ LOW_INCOME, OLD $\wedge$ FEMALE $\wedge$ HIGH_INCOME}. i.e., $|S_i|=4$. In the above example I presented the most simple case where $|S_i|=1$.

Each simulated day the population of 10,000 users visits websites with some probability. Users can visit multiple websites, so 10,000 impressions is the minimum number of impressions (i.e., supply of impressions) that agents can target. So the supply for a relevant set of segement $s \in S_i$ is $W(s)$, and the overall supply of relevant impressions is at least $W(S_i)$ each day.

[User Segment Population Data used in the Game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTsPr.png)

Agents bid a budget $B_i$ for the campaign $C_i$. Because the auction is second-price, bidding the true valuation for the item is a weakly dominant strategy. The authors desribe that they determine their agent's private value for a campaign as: $PrivateValue = PI * CI$ where $PI$ is the estimated cost for a single impression on a user during the next single or next multiple days (*PI=Price Index*). *CI* stands for *Competing Index*. *CI* is a parameter that scales the private value by intensity of competition for contracts (increase bids if agent lost previous auction, decrease bid in next auction if it won). For simplicity, assume that $CI=1$ so we're only left with *PI* to determine *Private Value*.

In particular, the authors define the *PI*, i.e., the one-day estimate of cost per impression for a segment $s$ on day $t$ as its *popularity*. Assuming an evenly paced spending of campaign budget the the *popularity* $pop(s,t)$ is defined as:

$$pop(s,t) = \sum_{s \in S_i \wedge t \in T_i} \frac{R_i}{W(S_i)|T_i|}$$

Hence, the authors define the *popularity* over a set of segments *S* over the course of a set of days *T* as:

$$pop(S,T) = \frac{\sum_{s \in S, t \in T} W(s)*pop(s,t)}{|T| * W(S)}$$

The latter formula corresponds to the PI for multi-days, i.e., gives us an estimate of how much the agent needs to spend for a single impression over the length of an advertising campaign that targets a specific set of segments. More specifically, given that $pop(S,T)$ corresponds to the estimated cost per impression for a set of targeted segments in contract $i$, i.e., $S_i = S$, that runs over $T=T_i$ gamedays, the budget (i.e., the bid) should be (at least) as high as the estimated cost per impression multiplied by the required reach.

My goal is to understand the formula so I can implement it myself in a slightly modified version of the agent-based simulation.

To this end, consider the example from above where a contract $C_1(R_1, S_1, T_1)$ is generated in the simulation. Let $R_1 = 500$, $S_1 =${$s_{11} =$ {YOUNG $\wedge$ FEMALE $\wedge$ LOW_INCOME}}, such that $W(S_1)=1980$ and $|S_1|=1$, and $T_1=\{1, 2, 3\}$, i.e., $|T_1| = 3$.

How does one calculate $pop(s_{11},t_{1j})$ $\forall j \in \{1, 2, 3\}$ and $pop(S_1, T_1)$ respectively?

Comment: Maybe there are other $S_i$ such that $s\in S_i$?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Given a Set $S_1$ $i=1$ is exogenously given. There does exist $S_2$ such that $s \in S_2$ is possible as well. But, for the evaluation of $y(s,t)$ this is irrelevant.

Comment: Why is it irrelevant? Such notation suggests that $i$ is bounded - sum is over all $i$-s s.t. the expression is true.

Comment: Yea but why can't you have $s=s_{11}=s_{25}$ for example? I feel that if $i$ is an dummy variable, it should not be fixed externally. That is, your sum cannot be a function of $i$. For example, $\sum_{i=1}^n i$ is not a function of $i$. Similarly, $\sum_{j=1}^m  a_{ij}b_{jk}$ is not a function of $j$. Can you please give the full context so that we can point out where you are confused? Thanks.

Comment: I provide the context in the main post due to max. char restrictions in comments. See above under "Edit:" for more context.

Comment: I'll let you finish editing before reading it. By the way, consider adding the "notation" and "summation" tags.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the original notation $y(s,t) = \sum_{s \in S_i \wedge t \in T_i} \frac{R_i}{W(S_i)|T_i|}$ can be better understood as

$$y(s,t) = \sum_{i\in I : s \in S_i \wedge t \in T_i} \frac{R_i}{W(S_i)|T_i|}.$$

Where $I$ is some index set. I believe it's the "day index" in your context. Presumably, because of how the $C_i$ are defined, you don't have to do an infinite summation here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Benjamin.

It is indeed a finite summation, hence it is not a series.

$i$ denotes the index of contract $C_i$, hence it is not really relevant for evaluation the function $y : s,t \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Still from your reply, I still can't figure out how to do the calculations for my presumably simple example above. Could you help me out on that?